# iReport palette sort button

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm editing a *JasperReports*'s report in *iReport* designer and I have a table that I want to make sortable by every column by clicking in the column head.

I have started adding sort buttons from the palette, and I have set the sort property, but every time I generate the report, the buttons never show up and there's nothing to click. There's only the table.

What's the best way to add sorting functionality to your table?

Answer (score 0):

The table itself contains the functionality of sorting,filtering and hiding the column.

So just a simple table would do.

Thanks